Unable to open the file-enabling Conan when building CMake (error C1083:No such file or directory)
Trying to run a project for an example Oat++ framework using Conan (in particular by running the cmake --build command. --config Release), I have a problem opening Conan inclusion files:
MSBuild version 17.10.4+10fbfbf2e for .NET Framework

  1>Checking Build System
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/h4thq/prjcts/oat2/oatpp-starter/CMakeLists.txt
MyController.cpp
C:\Users\h4thq\prjcts\oat2\oatpp-starter\src\dto\DTOs.hpp (4.10): error C1083: Cannot open file-enable: oatpp/
macro/codegen.hpp: No such file or directory, [C:\Users\h4thq\prjcts\oat2\oatpp-starter\build\my-project-lib.vcxproj]

Actions performed:

In the root directory of the project, run the command

conan install . --output-folder=build --build=missing


Going to the ./build directory, run the command

cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="conan_toolchain.cmake"


Immediately execute the command

cmake --build. --config Release

This is where the error appears.(
conanfile.txt:
[requires]
oatpp/1.3.0

[generators]
CMakeToolchain
CMakeDeps

CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

set(project_name my-project)

project(${project_name})

add_library(${project_name}-lib
    src/AppComponent.hpp
    src/controller/MyController.cpp
    src/controller/MyController.hpp
    src/dto/DTOs.hpp
)

## link libs

find_package(oatpp CONFIG REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(${project_name}-lib PUBLIC oatpp::oatpp)
target_include_directories(${project_name}-lib PUBLIC src)

## add executables
add_executable(${project_name}-exe
    src/App.cpp
    test/app/MyApiTestClient.hpp
)
target_link_libraries(${project_name}-exe ${project_name}-lib)
add_dependencies(${project_name}-exe ${project_name}-lib)

add_executable(${project_name}-test
    test/tests.cpp
    test/app/TestComponent.hpp
    test/app/MyApiTestClient.hpp
    test/MyControllerTest.cpp
    test/MyControllerTest.hpp
)

target_link_libraries(${project_name}-test ${project_name}-lib)
add_dependencies(${project_name}-test ${project_name}-lib)

set_target_properties(${project_name}-lib ${project_name}-exe ${project_name}-test PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 17
    CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
)

enable_testing()
add_test(project-tests ${project_name}-test)

The structure of the OATTP_STARTER project is:
./build
./src
./test
CMakeLists.txt
conanfile.txt

In catalogs ./src and ./test have other directories and project files.

Why do you re-ask the same question? Stack Overflow is not a help-me-faster site, it is a library of Questions/Answers which could be used not only by their authors.

BTW, in your previous question the error message was "Unable to open file enable". In the current question it is "Cannot open file-enable" (with dash). So, which variant represents the message which you actually got?

Your build steps and configuration are correct, no doubt.
Your error is because your source files can not find codegen.hpp.
Checking both the Conan recipe and upstream, we can find that header file in a different path:

https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/master/recipes/oatpp/all/conanfile.py
https://github.com/oatpp/oatpp/blob/1.3.0/src/oatpp/core/macro/codegen.hpp

So, you should update your source files to include the correct path:
#include "oatpp/core/macro/codegen.hpp"
The folder core is missing in your original code.
